# CMake can't find stdc++11 after Xcode 10 update

Tags: c++, xcode, cmake

I have a CMake project using SFML which was working fine but after updating to Xcode 10, all of the compiler files that CMake looks for can't be found.

`clang: warning: libstdc++ is deprecated; move to libc++`

I'm not sure how to move to the different lib source.

I've tried using `set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=libc++")` to use the flag.

It also tells me: `Check for working CXX compiler: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/c++ -- broken`. I can run the `g++/c++` commands fine in the terminal. I assume they are being looked for in the same spot.

CMake file I'm trying to compile with. Its the SFML one:
[SFML CMake](https://github.com/SFML/SFML/blob/master/CMakeLists.txt)

Full Error Message:

```
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/c++                                                                               
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/c++ -- broken

CMake Error at /Applications/CMake.app/Contents/share/cmake-3.7/Modules/CMakeTestCXXCompiler.cmake:44 (message):                                                                                            
  The C++ compiler                                                                                                                                                                                          
  "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/c++"                                                                                                              
  is not able to compile a simple test program.                                                                                                                                                             

  It fails with the following output:                                                                                                                                                                       

   Change Dir: /Users/DSchana/Documents/Libraries/SFML/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp



Run Build Command:"/usr/bin/make" "cmTC_af3d5/fast"

  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/make -f
  CMakeFiles/cmTC_af3d5.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/cmTC_af3d5.dir/build

  Building CXX object CMakeFiles/cmTC_af3d5.dir/testCXXCompiler.cxx.o


  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/c++
  -arch x86_64 -isysroot
  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.07.sdk
  -mmacosx-version-min=10.7 -o
  CMakeFiles/cmTC_af3d5.dir/testCXXCompiler.cxx.o -c
  /Users/DSchana/Documents/Libraries/SFML/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/testCXXCompiler.cxx


  warning: include path for stdlibc++ headers not found; pass '-std=libc++'
  on the command line to use the libc++ standard library instead
  [-Wstdlibcxx-not-found]

  1 warning generated.

  Linking CXX executable cmTC_af3d5

  /Applications/CMake.app/Contents/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script
  CMakeFiles/cmTC_af3d5.dir/link.txt --verbose=1


  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/c++
  -arch x86_64 -isysroot
  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.07.sdk
  -mmacosx-version-min=10.7 -Wl,-search_paths_first
  -Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names
  CMakeFiles/cmTC_af3d5.dir/testCXXCompiler.cxx.o -o cmTC_af3d5

  clang: warning: libstdc++ is deprecated; move to libc++ with a minimum
  deployment target of OS X 10.9 [-Wdeprecated]

  ld: library not found for -lstdc++

  clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see
  invocation)

  make[1]: *** [cmTC_af3d5] Error 1

  make: *** [cmTC_af3d5/fast] Error 2





  CMake will not be able to correctly generate this project.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:47 (project)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

Comment: Technically, this is just a **warning** about usage of deprecated library. Unless you have another errors, the project is still usable. Also, have you performed clean reconfiguration (delete build directory and run `cmake` again) after updating Xcode?

Comment: Yea, I tried building into a fresh folder so no cache or anything. I updated the question with the full error message at the bottom.

Comment: the CMakeLists.txt file probably has the reference to libstdc++ hardcoded.

Comment: @BradAllred I checked the CMakeLists.txt. Couldn't find any reference to libstdc++. It's the SFML CMake file I'm trying to compile right now btw.

Comment: can you post a link (or contents) of the CMakeList.txt file

Comment: Yep, just added it above the long error message in the question.

Comment: have you tried using `cmake .. -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS=-std=libc++`

Comment: `error: invalid value 'libc++' in '-std=libc++'` when I do. It suggests I use the standard `c++11` or other variation.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180760/discussion-between-brad-allred-and-dschana).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok. Turns out I just needed to add `set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-stdlib=libc++")` to my `CMakeLists.txt`